# Que hace exactamente la funcion getopt () ? de la libreria <unistd.h>?

Tags: c

Que hace exactamente esta función? y como podría aplicarla a mi código?

Comment: Lee este articulo y dime si aclara tu duda...
https://poesiabinaria.net/2015/11/como-gestionar-los-parametros-de-nuestros-programas-con-getopt-en-c/#un-pequentildeo-ejemplo-de-getopt

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque la información requerida es simplemente documentación

Answer (score 1):

`getopt` es una función que facilita la interpretación de los parámetros de inicio de la aplicación.

Hay multitud de programas que no tienen interfaz gráfica y la configuración se les facilita mediante línea de comandos:

```
ls -l -a
```

En el ejemplo anterior, `l` es un parámetro de configuración. Este parámetro podrías leerlo fácilmente usando `getopt`:

```
char c;
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "la:")) != -1)
{
  switch (c)
  {
    case 'a':
      // Parametro "a" presente
      // ...
      break;
    case 'l':
      // Parametro "l" presente
      // ...
      break;
  }
}
```

O podrías programarlo a mano (teniendo en cuenta que los parámetros pueden estar desordenados:

```
for( int i=1; i<argv; i++ )
{
  if( strcmp(argc[i], "-a") == 0 )
  {
    // Parametro "a" presente
    // ... 
  }
  if( strcmp(argc[i], "-l") == 0 )
  {
    // Parametro "l" presente
    // ...
  }
}
```

Fíjate que en este segundo caso los `if` son prácticamente iguales, lo que puede dar lugar a errores difíciles de detectar.

`getopt` tiene una extensa configuración para adaptarse a los diferentes tipos de entradas que se puedan necesitar.

Comment: Fenomenal!, Pero para que sirve el igualar la función al -1?

Comment: `getopt` es evaluado a `-1` para saber si se ha llegado al final de los argumentos "pasables" a la aplicación. @G-programmer